# Unable to apply to slice the __unicode__ property of object in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a model which store generic foreign keys to different objects. I am displaying the list somewhere and due to space constraint I want to splice the object name.

So I am doing the following

```
{{list_object.content_object|slice:":20"}}
```

but this does not work. However when I do

```
{{list_object.content_object.title|slice:":20"}}
```

the slicing works. However I cannot use this, as `content_object` is a `generic foreign key` and every object ma not have an attribute named title.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do slice directly on the object, Django never calls `__unicode__`, but rather passes the object directly into the filter. This is the actual behavior that should happen. When you do `{{ some_object }}` in your template, Django only auto-magically calls `__unicode__` for you because it needs to print out *something*.

Your best bet would be to add a method to your model to provide a shortened name, and then use that method in your template:

```
def MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_short_content_title(self):
        return unicode(self.content_object)[:20]
```

And in your template:

```
{{ list_object.get_short_content_title }}
```

Or technically you could merely proxy the `__unicode__` call and handle it in the template however you want:

```
def MyModel(models.Model):
    def get_content_title(self):
        return unicode(self.content_object)
```

And in your template:

```
{{ list_object.get_content_title|slice:":20" }}
```

Whichever works best in your scenario.

Actually one more alternative would be to create a simple template filter to return the unicode value of an object:

```
@register.filter
def get_unicode(obj):
    return unicode(obj)
```

Then, in your template:

```
 {{ list_object.content_object|get_unicode|slice:":20" }}
```

Don't you love options? ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for so many options!! The last one seems to be the most generic to me. That way I don't have to add a method to all my models I didn't know that Django automatically passes the object.

Answer (score 1):

list_object.content_object is an object, represented by a string. You can not slice an object of course. To solve your problem yout could try to explicitely call the **unicode** method:

```
{{list_object.content_object.__unicode__|slice:":20"}}
```

I haven't tried that, but it would be my first guess.

Comment: Django doesn't allow you to call underscored methods in template. But, that definitely would be the best way if you could ;).

Comment: Ah, ok. I knew that django doesn't allow to call methods with arguments, but thats new to me. Thanks, i'm not going to use that, unless i have forgotten about it until i need it ;)